# Why is re-compiled PHP using huge amounts of CPU compared to default Ubuntu build?

Tags: php, optimization, ubuntu, compilation

I have a multi-process PHP (CLI) application that runs continuously. Originally, I was using the standard Ubuntu 10.04 package build of PHP (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18). However, I am trying to optimize the memory usage because the amount of memory used by each process limits the number of forks that I can run at any given time (since I have a finite amount of memory available). Following the advice given by [preinheimer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877107/896660), I re-compiled PHP, disabling all extensions and then re-enabling only those needed for my application (mysql, curl, pcntl, posix, and json). My configure command is:

```
'./configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local/phpbare' '--with-config-file-path=/etc \
/php5/clibare' '--disable-all' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-curl' \
'--enable-pcntl' '--enable-posix' '--enable-json'
```

This new "bare bones" build allowed my application to run, but to my surprise, when I view the running process using `top`, it uses about the same amount of memory as before and (even more problematic), it uses *huge* amounts of CPU time (often 15-20% of CPU when before the amount reported by top was normally 0-1%). Is it possible that I am missing some php extension which somehow optimizes the script to use less computing resources??? Or is the Ubuntu build perhaps optimized for the Ubuntu architecture, whereas my custom build is lacking these optimizations? If so, how can I figure out which optimizations are used in the Ubuntu build, in order to re-create them in my "bare bones" build?

Here is a snippet of the output from `ps aux | grep php`, which is used to demonstrate my point in the comments below:

```
root  12952  0.3  0.9  33176  4968 pts/2    S    Feb14  11:15 s.php 5
root  12955  0.3  0.9  32664  4732 pts/2    S    Feb14  11:12 s.php 5
root  12958  0.3  0.9  32664  4796 pts/2    S    Feb14  10:51 s.php 5
root  12961  0.3  0.9  32740  4752 pts/2    S    Feb14  11:07 s.php 5
root  14162  0.3  0.9  33000  4904 pts/2    S    Feb14  10:51 s.php 5
root  14165  0.3  1.0  33256  5340 pts/2    S    Feb14  10:56 s.php 5
root  23426  9.5  1.1  13492  6040 pts/2    S    Feb15 151:38 s.php 1
```

Comment: are you using the same .ini file as you were on the stock ubuntu version?

Comment: Yep. I just copied it without modification to the directory specified by --with-config-file-path and confirmed this file was being used with php -i => Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/clibare/php.ini

Comment: what you really should be measuring is the speed at which the script runs, not CPU usage. You actually _want_ 100% of your CPU to be used when the script is running.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally agree, but the script is not doing its work any faster than before yet requiring much more CPU time. The reason I don't agree is that I have other processes running on the machine, and in fact, I would like to run 40-50 identical processes concurrently. If each one is requiring 15-20% of the CPU, I wouldn't get so far. Also, the reason that low CPU usage is expected is that the script is retrieving resources over a network and then processing the results. Most of the physical time is spent waiting to get the response back from the network before moving on...

Comment: ...Of course, I could try to make this happen asynchronously, but so far I haven't had a huge desire or need to go that route.

Comment: Building on what @Evert says, I think a better metric would be the total CPU time consumed by the process, when run with the stock Ubuntu PHP, and with your custom build. Use the `time` command on the command line to measure this. For example, `time ./script.php`

Comment: I understand where you two are coming from, but in this case it is very clear that the custom build is far less ideal than the stock build in terms of CPU usage. Maybe it would help if I explain a few details more clearly. This script is intended to be run *continuously*. A single execution of it could easily run for days or even longer, depending on how I configure it. The goal is collection and processing of data, retrieved over a network. I measure how much data is collected in a log file. The custom build is not performing any better, in terms of the rate of data collection, yet...

Comment: ...it is utilizing far more time of the CPU. Take a look at the output of ps aux, which I added to the question above. The first six lines are processes that were started several days ago using the stock version of php and have used 10-11 hours worth of CPU time. The last line is the custom build. It was started about a day later, but it has used roughly 15 times the amount of CPU time. All seven processes are collecting data at roughly the same rate, maybe within +/- 20%. The process using the custom build is *certainly* not doing 15 times those using the stock build!

Comment: Could you share your ./configure line (in `php -i`). Would be good to compare it to a stock ubuntu package.

Comment: Sure, I've added it above. Unfortunately, for the Ubuntu stock package, they have removed this information from phpinfo(). I've read that the only way to know the Ubuntu configuration details is to look at debian/rules to see how the build was made. It's not so straightforward. But at least you can now see my custom configuration. Please let me know if there is something clearly missing or wrong with it!

Answer (score -1):

Opcode cache makes PHP several times faster. Ensure you have extension such as [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) installed.

You could also check `phpinfo()` of the standard package to see what `configure` options it used and recompile with the same options to check whether that's a matter of configuration or something else, like different compiler or libraries.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Ubuntu standard package, the Configure Command line from phpinfo() is disabled. But otherwise, one can still gleam some configuration info from phpinfo(), just not the exact configure command.